# Is there a max scopes count on api manager?

Tags: wso2

I created 30 shared scope on the api manager, but when I create the resource, in the scope dropdown, there are only 25 scopes.
Is there a limit?

Comment: At the moment it loads only 25 scopes. I guess it needs to have some pagination option. Do you have more than 25 shared scopes?

Comment: Yes, I have more than 25 scopes. However, to resolve, I used local scopes :-)